# How do I create a Pandas Dataframe from a list that has all the values I'm seeking to include in the dataframe nested inside a recurring list element?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, python-3.7

The list looks like this.

```
[
  {
      "legal": [
          {
              "importance": 3,
              "notes": "",
              "updated": 19976,
              "date": 09/05/2020
          }
      ]
  },

  {
      "legal": [
          {
              "importance": 3,
              "notes": "",
              "updated": 15783,
              "date": 09/05/2020
          }
      ]
}
]
```

I want the columns to be "importance", "notes", "updated", and "date". I want to make the index the "date". I can't seem to find a way to make a pandas dataframe that way with the "legal" elements of the list where they are. I don't have to include them in the dataframe. That's just how I receive the data. I want to know the proper way to make this pandas dataframe. Make it look something like this.

```
| date *index | importance | notes | updated |
|-------------|------------|-------|---------|
| 09/05/2020  |      3     |  NaN  |  19976  |
|             |      3     |  NaN  |  15783  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for this

```py
In [33]: pd.json_normalize(data, 'legal').replace({'': np.nan}).set_index('date')
Out[33]:
            importance  notes  updated
date
09/05/2020           3    NaN    19976
09/05/2020           3    NaN    15783
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following list comprehension to get every dictionary's `legal` key and the first (only) dictionary, after that I replace the empty string with `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i['legal'][0] for i in lst]).replace('', np.nan)
```

And then:

```
print(df)
```

Will give:

```
         date  importance  notes  updated
0  09/05/2020           3    NaN    19976
1  09/05/2020           3    NaN    15783
```